# Select box option is overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have to prioritize my overlay div on the very top of all other html elements. But the select box option is overlapping above the overlay div. I have given the z-index and position property as well but the issue still exists. How to solve this?

```css
.overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.select-box {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.select-box option {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<select class="select-box">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<div class="overlay">
  <h3>Overlay</h3>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of this? I don't see the point of hiding the options under a div if your goal is to select an option from a dropdown select. It would be counterproductive to hide some of the options. I honestly think it is built so that it's over everything and that you can't manipulate its z-index, but I'm happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: In my application user can change the select box option even if the error popup comes out.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I have tried something and I can't seem to make it work as intended. But I think you would need to simulate a dropdown menu instead of using the select tag to make it work. I'll leave someone else to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here use this, but remember when you are adding more elements to the `div`'s just don't give it a fixed height. I have included bootstrap link also.

```css
#important {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="important" class="col"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="menu" class="col">
      <select class="select-box">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet isn't working and I don't understand why it should since you are not using any `z-index`?

Comment: Can you explain what is your problem? And what final out come will look like??, create a new html file copy the above snippet and run it in the browser.

Comment: I am not the OP but his issue is that he's trying to pop up a message that should stop a user from selecting an option (kind of like an adblock pop up appears, you can't interact with the website until you delete the popup or disable your adblocker)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```css
.overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.select-box {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}

.select-box option {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<select class="select-box">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<div class="overlay">
  <h3>Overlay</h3>
</div>
```